# Packaging common classes into WAR with maven and eclipse

Tags: java, java-ee-6, maven-3

I have two maven-based eclipse projects, one being a project with common classes and one a Java EE web application using these.

Now, I know the way to build the common project as a jar and add it as a dependency to the other.

But how would I solve it, if I want the common classes directly be included in the WAR's WEB-INF/classes?

And, will that mechanism work both within eclipse and from the command line running a maven command?

Comment: If you found any answers useful, or if they proved what your asked could not be done, be sure to accept and answer and vote them up :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to have two Maven projects. By declaring the packaging on your library as "jar" and the webapp as "war" maven will use the correct plugins to build your application as your described. Your scenario is fairly common, in addition to the information I'm about to give you, there is lots of info on this available in the Maven documentation.

Your library jar should be built with a pom similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Your webapp should be built with a pom similiar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject.mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject.mypackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When you build the webapp, maven will automatically include your library Jar in your web-inf/lib directory. Never ever place files manually in this directory, let Maven do the heavy lifting for you.

EDIT: The question was how to unpack a jar during the build, which is a very very bad idea for a multitude of reasons and bad practices. Persistence classes belong in an EJB, not in WEB-INF/classes. Doing this will also put you outside standard Java EE support... Nevertheless, here's the answer:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.myproject.mypackage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-lib</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting the old question, it can still be of use. But there's one detail in my question which you may have overlooked: My intention was not to add the jar file within WEB-INF/lib but to add the compiled classes from the common project directly under WEB-INF/classes as if they were part of the second project's source tree. The reason for that was the fact that the persistence configuration from common was not recognized when placed within a common.jar.

Comment: If this is a JEE project, your persistence classes should go into an EJB, not in WEB-INF/classes and they will be recognized automatically. I would *_STRONGLY_* advise sticking to best practices and follow this pattern.

If you really want to go about unpacking a jar, and are willing to accept the multitude of problems you will face in the future, you can use the maven dependency plugin to accomplish this.

Comment: You are right about best practices, my intention was not to violate them. Maybe I did something else wrong. I had my standard entity POJOs and put them into a common.jar. I also put the persistence.xml into it. But when using this jar in the war, the container was not able to use the entities and complained about it. That's why I tried to put the classes directly into the war. So, if you can point me to a sample project layouted in that way, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to use Entity Classes straight in your app, you could use Spring to instantiate a persistence container. This will really bloat your app though and Spring has it's own learning curve. If you're using Eclipse, create a new EJB project. Add the JPA2.0 Facet  to your project. Generate your persistence classes from your database connection in Eclipse. I do this all day at work, but I don't have a 'public domain' example, only tutorials...

Comment: Ok, I'll try your suggestions, but can't do it at the moment due to other topics, though I'll accept this as a solution. Anyway, I'll appreciate a link to a good tutorial in that direction!

Comment: Eclipse takes care of most of the boilerplate code... In the EJB you'll put the following: @PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em; Here's a easy to read reference to EJB3.0 http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/dependency-injection-in-ejb3 and here's a pretty simple tutorial on how to get started with EJB3.0 http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/ejb3/tutorial/stateless/index.xtp

Comment: If you want to get really fancy, maven can even generate your ejb-client jar!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) to unpack your .jar artifact containing the common classes to the target folder. You would also need to make your original dependency have the `provided` scope, so the classes are not included in both, the `classes` folder and (as a .jar) in the `libs` folder inside your resulting war.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But as I'm completely new to maven, I'm not sure, how to use it right. I adapted the example you pointed out, but it did not pack it into the deployed war within eclipse. Besides, it complained about not supporting unpack in m2e.